# Why "This app has been built with an incorrect configuration" error occured in some phones?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I Have build my app in android 6 without any error, but when I build my app in android 4.4.2 I get this error

```
This app has been built with an incorrect configuration.
 Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
```

and this is my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.faranegar.channel"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

note: when I set compileSdkVersion 23, every thing is fine and there isn't any error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This issue was alread reported here  [Issue 214182: appcompat-v7 24.0.0 is incompatible with rasterized vectors](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182).

One of the developer mention:

> What version of the Gradle plugin are you using?
>
> As of v2.0 of the Gradle plugin, library resources are never
>   rasterized so this should never happen.

The workaround for this is to update your Gradle by following this official link. [Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This worked well for me

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    generatedDensities = []
}

// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Notice this in the above code:

```
// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```

and

```
generatedDensities = []
```

**UPDATE**

If this `generatedDensities = []` is showing deprecated, use the following instead.

```
vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = []
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @ BlackPearl +1 vote for you. you saved my time Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you are using rasterized vector drawables

for Gradle plugin 2.0+

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
  }
}
```

for Gradle plugin before 2.0

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    ...  
  }

  aaptOptions {
   additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

you should add appcompat-v7 23.2.0+ to your build.gradle.for me,i am using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Comment: after adding vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true, I got this error, "Error:(14, 0) Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' " Please tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: @Woody check your gradle plugin version in build.gradle.'vectorDrawables' property is supported in gradle plugin 2+.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while implementing unit tests with JUnit and Robolectric. If that's your case maybe you need to add this to your gradle file, inside the `android` section. That's how I fixed it:

```
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
```