# I'm new to android dev,why I get this strange error?

Tags: android

this is my main Activity java file :

```
package com.example.fg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

and this is the layout of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.fg.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the error I get :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.fg, PID: 6946
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fg/com.example.fg.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009)
     at com.example.fg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009) 
     at com.example.fg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:67)
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:298)
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:229)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009) 
     at com.example.fg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

everytime I try to make a new blank app I get this problem,please help
back 7 days ago everything was working well but now after I got back from the holidays nothing wanna work.

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar

Comment: Try a different app:popupTheme

Comment: the error is "This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat." It is not the same as the one Amit linked. However, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143867/why-this-app-has-been-built-with-an-incorrect-configuration-error-occured-in-s may be related, so try to update your gradle version, if that fails post your gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extends AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
}
```

XML:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Then:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
            }
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html