# Toolbar: IllegalStateException - configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2. I started a new project with minSdkVersion as 19. My activity extends AppCompatActivity. The project starts with an empty activity using a fragment.

When previewing content_main.xml with API 24, all is good. when previewing API 19, I get the following rendering problem:

```
 The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat
```

I have added every thing I found relevant to the gradle (2 files):

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
>   **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true**
>   buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
>   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
>   **compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"**
>   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1

But still the error appears. I've found a lot of answers on internet. But none helped. Is there a problem using the new toolbar with API 19?

Comment: Just would like to point out that the "support design" dependency includes both the v4 and v7 libraries (in case you're trying to narrow down the problem)

Comment: facing same issue, could you resolve it ?

Answer (score 6):

This worked well for me

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    generatedDensities = []
}

// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Notice this in the above code:

```
// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```

and

```
generatedDensities = []
```

Answer (score 0):

from this google [**Issue**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182)

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}
```

check this issue for more help.

**UPDATE**

configured your app `build.gradle` file as follows

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Source
[**Age Of Vectors**](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.7359c69qs)

Comment: checkout this article [age of vector](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.7359c69qs)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are two types of gradle files.

1. `build.gradle(Project: ProjectName)`
2. `build.gradle(Module: app)`

For more information on these two files, go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28809406).

Coming to your question,

> I've found a lot of answers on the net but none helped. I'm using
>   Android Studio 2.1.2, my activity extends AppCompatActivity and added
>   to the gradle (2 files) every thing I found relevant: but still the
>   error appears.

From whatever you have posted, it seems like you didn't add right things at right places.

You shouldn't place your application dependencies in `build.gradle(Project: ProjectName)` - Android Studio says,

> // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>
> // in the individual module build.gradle files

Hence, replace your dependencies in `build.gradle(Project: ProjectName)` with below

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
```

Replace your dependencies in `build.gradle(Module: app)` with below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

After doing as mentioned above, you will see a "*Sync Now*" option on the Top Right. Click it. Android Studio will take care of remaining things.

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38143867/2818583) similar is to yours. Go through it. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Add :

**build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
}
```

And on top of your `Activity` class:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

And one last thing put your `vector drawables` inside any other drawables like `selector`, `LayerList`, etc. Something like below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_vector" />
</selector>
```

And use this above drawable everywhere instead of setting vector drawables directly. This will at other places as well whenever you want to use vector drawables on pre-lollipop devices.