# Getting IllegalStateException when using Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to use google/facebook/email authentication using firebase but I'm facing this error.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.

This occurs when I put the following in my gradle file (Moudle App)

> compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'

When I remove it, everything works fine.

Here's the full error log in case some one wants it:

```
08-12 14:53:02.454 2643-2643/com.example.demo_app2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.demo_app2, PID: 2643
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo_app2/com.example.demo_app2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                     at com.example.demo_app2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also I face the same issue when I set my compilesdk to 24. I cannot resolve the issue so I changed my compilesdk to 23 and changed my appcompat libraries from 24 to 23 and I don't get the error.

Can anyone throw some light on both of these cases?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143867/why-this-app-has-been-built-with-an-incorrect-configuration-error-occured-in-s

Comment: Yes, sorry I did a search but wasn't able to find it. My error got solved.
One last question, how do i change the versions for the new projects? Will i have to change description urls and classpaths for all new projects?