# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. while adding Firebase UI dependency

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I was adding Firebase UI depency but am getting a problem in syncing the project . Below is my `gradle` script.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pixsor.app.huzykamz.pixoradmin"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and below is the image of the error am getting , please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Android system will prevent the user from installing the
>   application if the system's API Level is lower than the value
>   specified in this attribute.

Check your error log .

You should change your `minSdkVersion` version at first .

```
    minSdkVersion 16 // 13 Conflict for your requirement
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart & Gradle**

**com.google.firebase:firebase** using min level 16 .

Comment: @Amiya it has worked , but still theres another error  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143867/why-this-app-has-been-built-with-an-incorrect-configuration-error-occured-in-s

Comment: But i have just opened up the project and added those dependencies , i haven't included Vector drawables