# Xamarin Android: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

Good afternoon,

I decided to play around with Xamarin today, and I've been having a few issues getting Vector images to work. I've followed the instructions [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportvectordrawable?version=23.2.1) and have the following in my layout:

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fort"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

However, I get the following error at runtime:

`Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat. occurred`

Throwing that error in Google, I get a few links, most notably, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143867/why-this-app-has-been-built-with-an-incorrect-configuration-error-occured-in-s) where most answers refer to the native Android SDK and include Gradle file modifications, but I'm not sure. I can't see any of the Gradle stuff from my VS project so I'm not sure I should edit them.

What should I do to fix this issue, is modifying the Gradle config the right answer?

Comment: Assuming you have changed your activity inheritance to `AppCompatActivity` and add `Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`?

Comment: @SushiHangover I have

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the [Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/) to your Xamarin.Android project.

> NOTE: The Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable nuget package contains a .targets file which appends the argument --no-version-vectors to AndroidResgenExtraArgs build property value to ensure the parameter is passed to the aapt invocation.

Which is basically the equivalent of editting the Gradle file. Information found here: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportvectordrawable?version=23.2.1

Comment: I've already added it, as well as switched my `Activity` class to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @James_Parsons I have updated my answer. Besides adding Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, you also have to add the Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable nuget package to your Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: @James_Parsons If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. If not, can you give us an update?